# Postgres: How to verify which certificate is being used for SSL

Tags: postgresql, ssl

On a Linux host, when I run the command `psql --set=sslmode=verify-full -h (rest of connection command...)` I connect to my postgres DB successfully. It also print information on the SSL connection cipher when my psql session begins. What confuses me is I can't figure out how the certificate used is being specified as I'm not listing any in my psql command. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/libpq-connect.html implies it defaults to stuff in a ~/.postgresql folder, but I don't have such a folder currently. I've seen references to environment variables like PGSSLROOTCERT mentioned elsewhere, but I don't have those set.

How do I determine which SSL certificate is being used? If it matters this is for a connection to an AWS RDS database.

Comment: Are you really still using Postgres 9.1?

Comment: Edited, I'm using 9.2. The server is 9.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> psql --set=sslmode=verify-full -h ...

This sets a "psql" variable named sslmode.  This variable makes no difference to anything.  So you are not actually doing verification of the server's cert.

Try setting sslmode in a supported way, like:

```
PGSSLMODE=verify-full psql -h ...
```

or

```
psql sslmode=verify-full -h ...
```

(But if you use this last one, then you cannot have a -d option hiding in the `...`)